# Unknown symbol dentry_path

Tags: linux, module, linker, kernel

I'm using the method `dentry_path` in my kernel module, compilation work fine but when loading the kernel module I go the error message:

> Error: could not insert module my_mod.ko: Unknown symbol in module

And in /var/log/kern.log

> May  8 19:45:10 zUbuntu kernel: [ 1173.105984] my_mod: Unknown symbol dentry_path (err 0)

This method is [declared like the following](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/dcache.h#L340):

```
extern char *dentry_path(struct dentry *, char *, int);
```

Could you please explain me why I can't link my module using this method ?

Comment: Isn't it *defined* as static, by any chance?

Comment: No it isn't: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/dcache.c#L2785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use dentry_path_raw instead of dentry_path, cause dentry_path isn't exported. Also, dentry_path_raw is the safer version between these two, it's protected with a writelock.